# How to extract the text using Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, gettext, getattribute

`getText()`, `getAttribute("textContent")` is not returning correct result.

This is the html tag with tag:

```
<span>
class="panel-title text-primary header-font ng-binding" ng-click="titleLink()" style="" xpath="1">Applied Configs: TEST, MSA TEST, MSACONFIGURABLE
</span>
```

Code trials:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name,'Applied Configs')]/div[1]")).getAttribute("textContent"));
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name,'Applied Configs')]/div[1]")).getText();
```

Returning `Applied Configs:` instead of complete Text `Applied Configs: TEST, MSA TEST, MSACONFIGURABLE`.

I am not sure what mistake I am doing here.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text **Applied Configs: TEST, MSA TEST, MSACONFIGURABLE** as the element is a dynamic element, you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `getText()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='panel-title text-primary header-font ng-binding' and starts-with(@ng-click, 'titleLink')]"))).getText());
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='panel-title text-primary header-font ng-binding' and starts-with(@ng-click, 'titleLink')]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```

---

### Update

As an alternative you can induce *WebDriverWait* for [`TextToBePresentInElementLocated()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_TextToBePresentInElementLocated.htm):

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='panel-title text-primary header-font ng-binding' and starts-with(@ng-click, 'titleLink')][contains(., 'Applied Configs:')]"), ","))
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='panel-title text-primary header-font ng-binding' and starts-with(@ng-click, 'titleLink')][contains(., 'Applied Configs:')]")).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Comment: Hello Debanjan, I used above mentioned code but it is printing first instant as with similar xpath I have total 3 element.

Comment: @SumitDhanawat Is there any specific text e.g. `TEST` or something else which is always expected within the innerHTML?

Comment: Applied Config: will always expected

Comment: @SumitDhanawat Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Getting timedoutException and not able to understand second line of code.

Comment: @SumitDhanawat My bad, second line was faulty, corrected it.

Comment: when I land on that page..... Applied Config tag is not visible is that the reason we are not getting complete text?

Comment: What is `Applied Config` tag? It seems part of the text only.

Comment: I realized that element is not visible at first place and that might be the reason that complete text is not printing on Consol. to avoid this I tried to add below line of code JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)"); but nothing is happening on screen